# How to move "an animated character" with rading "moves" from the text file into array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, readfile

I am creating a map and have an animated character move through the map.
I need to read 30 moves from a text file into a 1D array named moves[]. Each move is one of these letters: UDLR(for up, down, left, right respectively)

I tried the build the program and I created a map and successfully display "animated character" in the map, but can not move it around.

I think the problem is occuring when I am reading file.
This is the code that I wrote.

```
include "game.h"
#include "surface.h"
#include <cstdio> //printf
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace Tmpl8{
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    string moves[30];
    int bmap[10][16] =
    {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
        {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
        {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1}
    };

    Sprite theBackgroundSprite(new Surface("assets/map.tga"), 2);
    Sprite theMarioSprite(new Surface("assets/char.tga"), 4);
    int X = 1;
    int Y = 1;
    long int frameNumber = 0;
    void Game::Init()
    {
        string myNum;
        //Read "moves" from the text file into array
        ifstream MyReadFile("Text.txt");
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(MyReadFile, myNum))
         {
            moves[i] = myNum;
        }
        MyReadFile.close();
    

        //Draw background map

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                theBackgroundSprite.SetFrame(bmap[j][i]);
                theBackgroundSprite.Draw(screen, i * 50, j * 50);
            }
        }
     }

    void Game::Shutdown()
    {
    }

    static int frame = 0;
    static int moveNumber = 0;
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    void Game::Tick(float deltaTime)
    {
        frameNumber++;
        if ((frameNumber % 10) == 0)
        {
            if (moveNumber < 30)
            {
                moveNumber++;
                //Draw background map...
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                    {
                        theBackgroundSprite.SetFrame(bmap[j][i]);
                        theBackgroundSprite.Draw(screen, i * 50, j * 50);
                    }
                }
                if (moves[moveNumber] == "R") X++;
                if (moves[moveNumber] == "L") X--;
                if (moves[moveNumber] == "U") Y--;
                if (moves[moveNumber] == "D") Y++;
                theMarioSprite.SetFrame(moveNumber % 4);
                theMarioSprite.Draw(screen, X * 50, Y * 50);
                //update X and Y coordinates depending on the value (LRUD) from the 
 moves[] array
                //set the correct frame (1-4) from the Mario sprite
                //redraw the sprite
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgImq.png)

[text file img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Pv0.png)

Comment: Step through in a debugger to check various parts of your program are working correctly.  _"I think the problem happens when ...."_ types of statements on their own have no evidence to back them up.  Yes, you do have _potential_ problems reading the file, because you (A) assume the file was opened, (B) assume it contains 30 or fewer lines, (C) assume it has UTF-8 or ASCII-compatible encoding.  Beyond that, there may be other issues, and the _"cannot move it around"_ problem may or may not be related to what you think.  Test and isolate the issue, then ask a more specific question if necessary.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Otherwise it is very unlikely that anyone will use their precious time to hunt for bugs in your code, especially that they can actually be in the code you don't show and that you yourself did not go  through the debugging step required here.